# Cannot display the highest value when using crossfilter.js

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to display the top value, found by crossfilter, in dc.js, but I get

Uncaught TypeError: _chart.group(...).value is not a function

Any help?

This is my code

```
var ndx = crossfilter(projectsJson);
var highPriceDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.High; });
var highGrp = highPriceDim.top(1);
console.log(highGrp);

var highGrpND = dc.numberDisplay("#max-price-nd");
highGrpND.group(highGrp)
    .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
    .valueAccessor(function(d){return d ; })
    .formatNumber(d3.format(".4f"));
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

highGrp is an array. Try highGrpND.group(highGrp[0]) instead.

Comment: Oh, right, because value still isn't a function, just a number. You'll have to create a fake group. Take a look at the DC.js FAQ, which explains how to do that.

Comment: I am trying to understand these fake groups but i don't get them.. Never mind I will try to find another solution.

Comment: Share your code, or preferably a working example, and we may be able to help. If you can share a working example on JSfiddle or Codepen (for example), then someone will likely be able to provide a fix for that example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do

```
highGrpND.group(highPriceDim.group())
```

since the numberDisplay will look for either a `value` method, or failing that, take `.top(1)`

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/number-display.js#L81

(which is kind of a messy design, but hey if it works...)

This is better than calculating the top(1) at setup time, since it will be calculated every time the charts are drawn, rather than just once, which is probably what you want.